# Using SUMIF to Evaluate two rows of Data and output anwser to two specific cells

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas

My data looks like this:

> 1. 1  cs
> 2. 2  ea
> 3. 1  cs
> 4. 1  cs
> 5. 1  cs
> 6. 1  cs
> 7. 11 cs

There are numbers in the left column and quantity’s in the right

```
"CS" = Cases and "EA" = Each.
```

I have used this formula for each result Separately:

```
(CELLB8)=SUMIF(E2:E4,"CS",D2:D4)
(CELLC8)==SUMIF(E2:E4,"EA",D2:D4)
```

I need to combined these two "if" statement into one, but still have the output for "cases" and "each" in their Cells.
I don't know if this is even possible. I have looked everywhere for answer.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "combine them into one". Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear but if you want to visualize your answer in one cell next to each other you can use `&` for this:

```
=SUMIF(E2:E4,"CS",D2:D4) & "CS " & SUMIF(E2:E4,"EA",D2:D4) & "EA"
```

A little bit more detail as follows:

[image]

In the picture, 
cell (A9) = cumulation of "CS":

```
=SUMIF(B2:B8,"CS",A2:A8) & " CS "
```

cell (B9) = cumulation of "EA":

```
=SUMIF(B2:B8,"EA",A2:A8) & " EA"
```

cell (A10) = combines cumulations:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B8,"CS",A2:A8) & " CS & " & SUMIF(B2:B8,"EA",A2:A8) & " EA"
```

Comment: Thank you that is almost it. Using the Same formula I need the sum of cases in the same cell as the formula, but the sum for each in the cell to the right of it.

Cell A8                     
   12             
Cell B8             
   10           
where A8 is "cases" and B8 is "each".
 I hope that clarifies what I am trying achieve. Thank you!